Odoo 17 - UncaughtPromiseError > TypeError / Failed to fetch
TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at Object.get (https://www.x.com/web/assets/369e31e/web.assets_web.min.js:2874:92)
    at https://www.x.com/web/assets/369e31e/web.assets_web.min.js:15352:49
    at AddPageDialog.getCssLinkEls (https://www.x.com./web/assets/369e31e/web.assets_web.min.js:15353:91)
    at Object.getCssLinkEls (https://www.x.com/web/assets/369e31e/web.assets_web.min.js:15348:727)
    at AddPageTemplates.preparePages (https://www.x.com/web/assets/369e31e/web.assets_web.min.js:15343:37)
    at AddPageTemplates.<anonymous> (https://www.x.com/web/assets/369e31e/web.assets_web.min.js:15342:653)
    at https://www.x.com/web/assets/369e31e/web.assets_web.min.js:1005:80
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at ComponentNode.initiateRender (https://www.x.com/web/assets/369e31e/web.assets_web.min.js:1005:69)
    at https://www.x.com/web/assets/369e31e/web.assets_web.min.js:1541:80

I try to access Web Site Editor. Uncaught promise error and never show.

Activate the developer mode with assets and try again. And if the error persist the error log will be clear.

I activate the developer mode with assets and try againg. I add the error: UncaughtPromiseError > OwlError
Uncaught Promise > The following error occurred in onMounted: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'body')"
